# How to replace the QListWidget's icons with a custom widget?

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

Currently I have a `QListWidget` with `viewMode` set to `Icon`.

Is there a way to use a custom widget or painting instead of icon?

```
mTestLV = new QListWidget;

mTestLV->setIconSize(QSize(128, 128));
mTestLV->setViewMode(QListView::ViewMode::IconMode);

auto icon = QIcon("../../Resources/PCPP.jpg");

for (size_t i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    mTestLV->addItem(new QListWidgetItem(icon, "naaaame"));
```

Comment: QListWidgetItem does not inherit from QWidget. So you're not able to use widgets instead of items (displayed as text/icon).

Comment: If you want to override display of (list) items, please, have a look at [QStyledItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setItemWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#setItemWidget) to display a widget in a QListWidgetItem.  Just create a QListWidgetItem, add it to your QListWidget, then set your custom widget on the item:

```
QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem();
CustomWidget *custom = new CustomWidget();
mTestLV->addItem(item);
mTestLV->setItemWidget(item, custom);
```